# How to convert time 24-hour to AM/PM and remove nanoseconds & seconds via time4j?

Tags: java, time, java-time, time4j

I'm faced with the issue that I need to convert time from 24 format to AM/PM format (and vice-versa) removing redundant values such as nanoseconds and seconds by time4j library.

**I'm using the time4j library because Java can't handle Windows Time Zones and I have to convert them via time4j**

Conversion from 24 hour format to AM/PM will depend on users localization. And I want to transmit it (localization) as an argument. Localization will look like "en-US" string.

**For example:** If users localization is "en-US" then convert 24 hour format to AM/PM. Else keep current value.

Or maybe it's better to get time in the format I need when I already define localization of my user?

**Any ideas how to do this?** Please help)

I have to spend a lot of time reading [time4j doc](http://www.time4j.net/javadoc-en/) but my mind is blown

**To have full scale of what I'm doing and what the purpose all of this:**

I have to get users timeZone from my DB which corresponds to Windows Time Zones and convert them to IANA time zones. I already did this by this method

```
WindowsZone wzn = WindowsZone.of(userTimeZoneId); //userTimeZoneId="eg. FLE Standart Time"
TZID winZone = wzn.resolveSmart(new Locale("","001"));
System.out.println(winZone.canonical()); // WINDOWS~Europe/Kiev
```

Where "userTimeZoneId" is timeZone from DB. It corresponds to [Microsoft Name of Time Zones](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/973627/microsoft-time-zone-index-values)

My next step is to get time / or time stamp from users time zone which I already convert to IANA time zones.

I did like this:

```
PlainTime currentTime = SystemClock.inZonalView(winZone).now().toTime(); 
//currentTime: "T17:31:37,057"
```

Where "winZone" converted timeZone (eg. "WINDOWS~Europe/Kiev")

**So now returning to my problem I described at the top of the post.**

1. Maybe it's better to get time in the format I need when I already define localization of my user?
2. How can I convert time from 24 format to AM/PM and vise-versa?
3. How to remove redundant values such as nanoseconds and seconds?
4. How can I use user localization in conversion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting XX:XX AM/PM to 24 Hour Clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316089/converting-xxxx-am-pm-to-24-hour-clock)

Comment: Why not use Java's LocalDateTime?

Comment: Because Java's LocalDateTime can't handle with Windows Time Zones. That's why I have to use time4j library. If there any possibility to resolve my issue using Java LocalDateTime - i will be really grateful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is straight forward as long as you know that the dedicated formatter API in Time4J is based on [ChronoFormatter](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/ChronoFormatter.html):**

```
Locale ukraine = new Locale("en", "UA"); // or use new Locale("en", "001") for worldwide
TZID winZone = WindowsZone.of("FLE Standard Time").resolveSmart(ukraine);
PlainTime currentTime = SystemClock.inZonalView(winZone).now().toTime();
System.out.println(currentTime); // T12:02:40,344

// truncate seconds and nanoseconds
currentTime = currentTime.with(PlainTime.PRECISION, ClockUnit.MINUTES);
System.out.println(currentTime); // T12:02

// format in am/pm-notation
ChronoFormatter<PlainTime> f1 =
    ChronoFormatter.ofTimePattern("h:mm a", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.US);
String formatted1 = f1.format(currentTime);
System.out.println(formatted1); // 12:02 pm

// or use styled formatter (which has only limited control over displayed precision)
ChronoFormatter<PlainTime> f2 = 
    ChronoFormatter.ofTimeStyle(DisplayMode.SHORT, Locale.US);
String formatted2 = f2.format(currentTime);
System.out.println(formatted2); // 12:02 pm
```

A style-based solution (as demonstrated above for Time4J) is appropriate if you want to let the locale control the format pattern. For example, a german locale would print "12:02" instead of "12:02 pm" (US).

**By the way, you are also free to use the format-API of `java.time` if you want because `PlainTime` implements the JSR-310-interface `TemporalAccessor`:**

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a", Locale.US);
System.out.println(dtf.format(currentTime)); // 12:02 PM
```

Here the different capitalization originates from the fact that the JDK (at least on my system) still uses older CLDR-data for internationalization while Time4J has its own resources based on actual CLDR-version v33. [A future Java version will surely change the capitalization](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8202537). In general, I still recommend to use `ChronoFormatter` for sake of more features, better i18n and more performance. For example, the reverse way of parsing am/pm-literals is more reliable using Time4J than in `java.time` if you work with different locales.

If you like to use "AM" and "PM" in capitalized letters (or any other customized format) together with `ChronoFormatter` then you can also use:

```
Map<Meridiem, String> map = new EnumMap<>(Meridiem.class);
map.put(Meridiem.AM, "AM");
map.put(Meridiem.PM, "PM");
ChronoFormatter<PlainTime> f3 =
    ChronoFormatter
        .setUp(PlainTime.axis(), Locale.ROOT)
        .addPattern("h:mm ", PatternType.CLDR)
        .addText(PlainTime.AM_PM_OF_DAY, map)
        .build();
String formatted3 = f3.format(currentTime);
System.out.println(formatted3); // 12:02 PM
```

Comment: Thank you man! You really help me) It's working! Small modifications and adaptation will help me make methods more flexible)